# AutoFill Explanation

Tags: excel, vba

I know this questions been asked tons of times but I've attempted to use solutions from other answers and haven't been able to get it to work for my excel macro.

I have;

`Range("G2").Select`

`Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G870")`

However, G870 will not always be the final cell of the ending part of the range. I was hoping so it automatically picks up on whatever the range is based on the final data entry in column F. I'm not sure how to code this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba):

```vb
Range("G2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)
```

Comment: Where do I add this into the code? Do I replace the 2nd line in my post or both?

Comment: You replace both lines. `Range("G2").Select` is unnecessary, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Hey Ben, if I wanted to do this same mechanic but auto fill columns G to J. What would I swap in the code?

Comment: `Range("G2:J2")` and `Range("G2:J"....` probably @LittleAuditorium.